# Remove items from HashMap by key in java

Tags: java, android, dictionary, hashmap

I have one HashMap like this

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> jsonPosition = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

I put some values like this in my hashmap

```
GlobalClassParameters.jsonPosition.put("another income",
                        GlobalClassParameters.jsonPosition.size());
```

Now I want to remove the items by their key. I wrote some code that can remove all items with a key equal to some value.

```
Object objectToRemove = null;
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iter = GlobalClassParameters.jsonPosition.entrySet().iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
   Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iter.next();

   if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("another income"))
   {
      objectToRemove = entry;
      break;
   }  
}                               

if(objectToRemove != null)
{
   GlobalClassParameters.jsonPosition.entrySet().remove(objectToRemove);
}
```

My problem is that I don't need to remove all objects with keys equal to my "Another Income", but I want to remove only one object with that key.

Comment: Do do you which one to remove?

Comment: yes only one object @ Rohit5k2

Comment: A `Map` like `HashMap` has only **one** value for each key. When you remove a key, you remove the associated value. If you want more, you should use a `MultiMap`.

Comment: After I know tried to clean up your question a bit, I understood your question. Since hashmaps hold key value pairs, they only have ONE value for each key, so it is simply not possible to have multiple integers for the key "Another Income".

Answer (score 3):

You can't put multiple values for a single key in `HashMap`. You are just overwriting your previous value for this key.

Besides Maps do have a [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) methods, which accepts a key and removes the entry for this key.

Answer (score 2):

A HashMap in Java just holds one value per key.

```
"Income"           => 4500
"Another Income"   => 6700
"Third Income"     => 2400
```

So if you ask the HashMap to remove the integer behind the key "Another Incomse", there only is one value which is removed.

**The following is not possible with a HashMap!!**

```
"Income"           => 4500
"Another Income"   => 6700
"Another Income"   => 5300
"Third Income"     => 2400
```

Using this code

```
HashMap<String, Integer> incomes = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
incomes.put("Income", 4500);
incomes.put("Another Income", 6700);
incomes.put("Another Income", 5300);
incomes.put("Third Income", 2400);
```

will lead to this:

```
"Income"           => 4500
"Another Income"   => 5300
"Third Income"     => 2400
```

since the second time you assign a value to "Another Income", you just overwrite your first entry.

Comment: i put some objects with "Another Incomse" key and  when i deleted "Another Incomse" and then print my hashmap-- hashmap is empty

Comment: Yes, because every time you put an integer for the key "Another Income", you overwrite any existing integer for this key. There can only be ONE value for each key, that is how HashMap (or maps in general) work in Java.

Comment: what is a solution? can you show me some examples or if you can to rewrite my code .thanks

Comment: How can I help you if you do not even tell us what you are trying to achieve?! Tell us what you trying to do and we can help you. Why did you choose a hashmap and what is your software meant to do?

Comment: i try to explain you my problem.i have some list.and in list click i remove items in list by position(for example i have 4 items in list,that means i  put "AnotherIncom" object in my hashmap) and if i deleted some values in my list also want to remove  One "AnotherIncome" key object in my hashmap.

Comment: But as I (and @Samuil Yanovski) are desperately trying to tell you, there can only be ONE entry to "Another Income", so you CANNOT save more than one number for a key named "Another Income"

Comment: public static ListMultimap<String, Integer> map = ArrayListMultimap.create(); @Phiwa now i will try it.what can you tell me about me solutions?

Comment: Again: What are you trying to achieve? Why do not need to store multiple values for one key? What is the purpose of your software? What are you trying to store? If you finally tell me that, I can come up with a solution for that, e.g. with a ListMultiMap or e.g. a HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>, a HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> or something completely different.